# On geonodes, how do I apply normalization on two measurements

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to normalize input measurements but I'm lost.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: my objective reference image]

I want to resize the quadrilateral so that it keeps touching the inner and outer circles even if I change the parameters.

The position offset part seems to work, but for the quadrilateral width, it appears I might need to perform some normalizing because directly subtracting Inner and Center input fields doesn't work.

[image: reference nodes]

However, I don't know how I can normalize the two parameters. The first normalization probably works, but the second one doesn't. I probably need to fill in the selection but I don't know how to connect it.

And here's the reference .blend file.
[image]

ADDENDUM:
If I remove the connection to compute for the width and the corresponding normalization, the quadrilateral seems to follow the Inner and Center input fields correctly albeit having an incorrect width.
[image: reference #2]

If I connect the width, and the first set pos while leaving the 2nd set pos, changing the Inner input field seem to work, but not the Center input field as expected.
[image: ref #3]

That is where I think I got stuck, how to make both set positions work. Or, I maybe doing all these the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure whether you mean like this?

[image]

so here is the node tree for that:

[image]

Comment: I wonder, does @sophia want to close the small gap at the tangent of the inner ring?

Comment: wow, I overthink the problem, I thought it has something to do with normalization, I didn't realize it is just a simple averaging of values 